# "The type Gallery is deprecated", Whats the best alternative?

Tags: android, imageview, gallery

I was really surprised that such a Widget gets deprecated.
I want a simple gallery that scrolls left and right, shows a picture on the whole Activity screen, and most important is that you cant swipe more than 1 image in any direction, even if the scroll speed is fast it changes to the next image.

So which Widget should I use? Or should I use a simple ImageView and handle all the swipes and add an animation?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It states in the docs:

> This widget is no longer supported. Other horizontally scrolling widgets include HorizontalScrollView and ViewPager from the support library.

HorizontalScrollView will be closer to what you are looking for I think.

I suspect that Gallery was deprecated because it did not properly use convertView with its adapter. Which meant that it had to create a new view for every item which was a drain on performance.

Another option you have is to use the [3rd party created EcoGallery](https://github.com/falnatsheh/EcoGallery) which Joseph Earl created to overcome the issue, this version does recycle its views properly. <strike>Unfortunately that [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/FWyYTt4D) is the only reference to it I can find online now.</strike>

Comment: If OP wants only 1 image to be swiped at a time, wouldn't ViewPager the closer one? Unless he wants it to be continuous...