# Swipe Screen with Grid View images

Tags: android

I wanted to create a swipe screen with grid view of images from gallery.Though I have created a grid view from gallery but creating horizontal view swipe I m finding it difficult...

Could Anyone give to a shorthand example or link to create it

Similar to what we see in our Android Mobile Phones

Any Answer is Appreciated...

Comment: Do you really need a `HorizontalScrollView`, or would be a `ViewPager` an alternative? For `HorizontalScrollViews` as a `horizontalListView` look at this tutorial: http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

Comment: 1)I wanted to have grid of images on a screen 2)Swipe the Screen horizontally to get the next screen with remainder images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Gallery but Gallery is deprecated in API version 16, so have to go with some alternatives...

try these links

["The type Gallery is deprecated", Whats the best alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868503/the-type-gallery-is-deprecated-whats-the-best-alternative)

https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/

https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl

http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html

Comment: try this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919060/how-to-make-grid-view-scroll-horizontally-not-vertically-in-android