# Horizontal scroll over a list of Image views

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview, horizontallist

After going through several third party as well as android default components I can't find a way through which I can implement a **dynamic horizontal Scroll List View** where the List is a list of image urls handled by my custom Adapter.

I even tried this [DevSmartLib - Android](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android) but this doesnot work with fragment. I can't really figure out the reason but the rendered view is not being shown with the **fragment** but it works fine with simple Acitvity.

Other possibilites are:

- Gallery View

  *It has been depreciated by Android in API - 16*
- Horizontal Scroll View with a Grid View as its root element

  *I havn't tried this but based on the developer community I think we cant achieve a horizontal scroll even if we force the grid view to be of one row*

**Has any one done this before or can any one help me with this as all I need is to have a horizontal scroll over a list of image views that I am fetching from facebook.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868503/the-type-gallery-is-deprecated-whats-the-best-alternative

Comment: Scroll View scrolls over only one view and not over the entire list which my second possibility already states. But have you used this eco gallery ? .

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal Scroll View is only good if you have just a few items. If you have a lot, you should consider an alternative: a [**ViewPager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) (in case you wish to show only a single item at a time), or a third party library like [**"Horizontal Variable ListView"**](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView). I'm sure there are other alternatives.

note that the Gallery view is very inefficient and buggy so you shouldn't even try to use it.

Comment: Regarding ViewPager : I dont want to show one item at a time. They are like 4 or 5 items at a time.

Regarding third party Library: I have already tried Dev Smart lib as mentioned in my question but these third party library a bit buggy as this was not working for me with the fragment

Comment: Is it the same library I've linked to ?