# how to fix gallery is obsolete error(CS0618) in visual studio?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, obsolete

I was working on an android wallpaper app in visual studio and got this error mentioned above. I included Gallery and some ImageAdapter code from xamarin website here is the link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/gallery/. when i finally compile, It says Gallary is obsolete in my mainactivity.cs file.

```
 namespace wallpaperApp
 {
   [Activity(Label = "wallpaperApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Gallery gallery = (Gallery)FindViewById<Gallery>(Resource.Id.gallery);

        gallery.Adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        gallery.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args) {
            Toast.MakeText(this, args.Position.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
        };
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The type Gallery is deprecated", Whats the best alternative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868503/the-type-gallery-is-deprecated-whats-the-best-alternative)

Comment: Or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833889/options-for-replacing-the-deprecated-gallery

Comment: Besides me being new to c# android programming, the two sources you listed are in java. I am looking for c# code.

Comment: Converting from java to C# is fairly easy, take it line by line, the Java APIs that you are calling with C# are the same... and XML-based Layouts used are identical...

Comment: ok, I used ecogallery and went through the process and come across this "Include 'EcoGallery' android library to your project. (Eclipse project: properties -> Android -> Library - Add)", how do i do that in visual studio? do i download the files from github and add them in reference folder?

Answer (score 0):

The Gallery widget in Android is now obsolete and should be replaced with something else. Some possible solutions can be found on the Xamarin forums:

> Working with multiple images/bitmap in Xamarin.Android (and, actually,
>   in Android in general) is quite tricky. I'd suggest you to use on of
>   the image downloaders 3rd parties such as Universal Image Loader,
>   Glide, Picasso and so on. Also take a look at
>   https://github.com/rdio/tangoandcache it works good with xamarin's GC
>   and utilizes Bitmap Reuse.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45567/gallery-imageview-explodes-memory